# Limits on upvoting comments?

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, comment-votes

What is the daily limit for upvotes on comments and why is there a limit?

Since comments are ephemeral and don't have any effect on rep why would anyone care how many upvotes a person uses each day on comments?

Comment: Everything on The Stack is rate-limited.  And I do mean everything.  Imagine me putting an upvote on every comment in a long comment chain.  That would put a bit of a damper on the auto-hiding of unremarkable comments mechanism, wouldn't it?

Comment: I just had this really weird thought go through my mind about not being able to use an 'R' in a post as the day wears on. Then losing the 'P', etc... It would @RobertHarvey, but where is this limit specified? Is it dependent on rep? Do I get that vote back if that comment is deleted? Now that I know I can be more judicious in my use of comment rep.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do you really upvote that many comments that this is a concern?

Comment: Not until today @bluefeet. And it really isn't a concern, just a question given all that I have read on comments being ephemeral.

Comment: Sorry I just had to do it ;-)

Comment: Can anyone help me find the most upvoted comment on StackOverflow( not meta )?

Comment: @self. [Top 25 Comments on SO by Score](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/197453/255697/top-25-comments-by-score)

Comment: @self. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#comment8132296_6841479) I think; [source](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197454)

Comment: @aerox gah, 32 seconds! mind you mine has a `[Post Link]` column ;)

Comment: @AeroX AakashM Thank you!

Comment: @AakashM Ahh, now I've read the help I understand how magic columns work ([Updated, Top 25 Comments on SO by Score](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197453/top-25-comments-by-score))

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You get 30 votes per day, but you do not get votes back if the post they are on is deleted. <sub><sup>[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18995/238586)</sup></sub>

One of the many similar reasons for a daily limit is because otherwise, it would be easy to create a script that votes for a random comment every five seconds. over 17 thousand random comment votes every day (assuming only one of the few million users of Stack Overflow used this script) is *not* good for the site. There is a combined total of about 19 million comment votes on Stack Overflow right now. In about three years, *one person* could vote that many times—if there was no limit.

Comment: What would be the point of such a script? Kill the site?

Comment: Just having fun I guess...

Comment: Experiment before moving onto something that actually effects a users's rep ?

Comment: @Jonas What's the point of trolling? There are people out there who take satisfaction in the misfortune of others.

Comment: I think there are easier ways to troll the site than a random comment upvoting script that seems ridiculously to detect.

Comment: Haven't you heard the famous question: "but, why?" And the famous answer "because I can!". There are loads of people who would have done anything just to say they can!

Comment: I believe it could be stopped by having a captcha every 20 upvotes stopping the bot if they don't complete the captcha. This would definitely slow down any script.

Comment: possibly, however a daily limit is much simpler and less intrusive.

Comment: @BlueRobin sure, but you still have the problem of someone bored and wanting to mess with the site manually entering the captchas.  A more relevant question is why anyone would need to upvote more than 30 comments per day.

Comment: @RyanM Maybe if they are SUPER active. With a captcha + a cooldown for each upvote, it would be extremely hard to actively upvote random comments on Stack Overflow. Anyone who would do that would be the definition of insane.