# Why can you vote on comments after reaching the daily vote limit?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that if I use all 40 of my daily votes, I can still vote on comments. Why is this?

Comment: These use a different counter.

Comment: I think you answered your first question with your second question. Yes, there is no quota on votes for comments, because votes on comments don't count for reputation -- so there is no reason to game them.  As to comments not having reputation, it's because they're considered temporary second class citizens on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There is *definitely* a quota on daily votes for comments, @stephan. I forget the exact number, but it is something like 30 or 40. I hit it regularly on Meta. Almost never on main.

Comment: Related: [Limits on upvoting comments?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256384)