# Removal/increase of the daily vote limit on Meta

Tags: feature-request, rate-limiting

There's been posted quite a number of questions regarding the daily vote limit before, but I am puzzled as to why none of them seem to address Meta, just the main site. I was just met with this:

[image]

It's pretty self-explanatory to me why there shouldn't be a limit on Meta, considering the voting policy/culture on here. Almost all of my votes today, have been cast in the same thread, and I am therefore being limited on participating in other discussions on MSO today, as we express agreement or disagreement through voting.

In order for us to fully participate on MSO, could we have the daily voting limit removed/increased on Meta?

**–––––––––––––––––– Revision ––––––––––––––––––**

Based on what's been brought up in comments and [Cody's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386697/7395227), the point of making us carefully consider on which posts we cast our votes on, is important in this discussion, but it still doesn't necessarily work as good as it's supposed to. As what I've attempted to get through, and [Dukeling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling) and [Mark Amery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery) have spelled out in [comm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386675/removal-increase-of-the-daily-vote-limit-on-meta?noredirect=1#comment708376_386697)[ents](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386675/removal-increase-of-the-daily-vote-limit-on-meta?noredirect=1#comment708431_386697) to [Cody's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386697/7395227), some users participate little, and never have a problem with the limit, but when some users do happen to participate very much, the voting limit can be a problem. Maybe we should therefore shift the discussion to how much the limit should be increased with?

Comment: Related: *[Limits on upvoting comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256384)*. E.g. the vote limit appears to be 30.

Comment: It would be more realistic to ask for a higher limit.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Can you rollback your edit? This is not only for comments, but **all voting**. I have already looked at the question you linked. I created a new question, because I ask for removal of the voting limit for **any** post (**answer/comment/question**) on **Meta** sites, not main sites.

Comment: @Andreas you can do it yourself too btw. As the owner of a post, you have rollback privileges regardless of editing privileges (rollbacks require 2k rep if you're not the owner of a post). I've done it for you this time, but if you take a [look at the revision list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/386675/revisions), you'll see a "rollback" button. Click rollback on the revision you want to roll back to, and the post will be reverted to its former state.

Comment: @Zoe No, there was no rollback button on Peter's edit, neither on any other. The rollback button is there now, on every edit other than your rollback. Thank you.

Comment: @Andreas I probably should've specified it's only available on other revisions, and never on the last one. So if you want to undo revision 3, you need to click rollback on revision 2. The rollback button rolls back *to* a specified revision, which is probably why you didn't see it.

Comment: I would +1 this question but I'm out of votes :(

Comment: I'll say... take break - go for a walk, enjoy the sun or something that doesn't involves a computer. Once you have used all your votes, you have probably contributed all that can be expected. There's more to life than SO-meta....

Comment: @4386427 Who are you to tell others how they should spend their freetime? What if I'm outside for 10 hours a day and want to spend 4-5 hours moderating SO before I got to sleep and spend another 10 hours outside?

Comment: I think you should be more clear in the question about which vote limit(s). There are two vote limits: a comment vote limit (30) and a post vote limit (40). (The comment vote limit is usually easier to hit than the post vote limit, as there are usually many comments for each post (at least for the interesting posts).)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I hit the limit after voting for comments. I was unable to continue voting for posts too. When one limit is hit, are both invoked? Now, shouldn't there be only one limit, and not two, and if there still should be two, why is the vote limit for comments lower than that for answers/questions???

Answer (score 32):

You're right in observing that votes on Meta generally connote agreement or disagreement, certainly to a much greater extent than on the main site. However, this does not imply that you should have unlimited votes.

**The purpose of the daily voting limit isn't to restrict your participation—rather, it's to make you carefully consider the content for which you decide to vote.** Having a daily vote limit forces you to only vote on the comments or posts that you truly feel strongly about, rather than scattering votes all over the place.

That's true on the main site, too, regardless of the reasons for which you are voting. One could make a similar argument that Stack Overflow gets so many questions that users should be given more votes than other sites with less traffic. With so many questions and answers being posted every day, it's reasonable to assume that there are more than 30–40 that are worth a vote. You have to make your vote count!

Comment: The problem is that the limit is, at least, too low. It limits too much. If participating much one day, in relatively long discussions, there can be many views one's interested in supporting with a vote. Yes, of course there's a point in carefully considering the content which to vote for, but the current limit doesn't correspond to a realistic amount of posts to feel strongly about. I see the point in making unlimited voting a problem, and if this reason is to weigh, shouldn't we at least increase the limit?

Comment: I'm a pretty active participant on Meta, with rather strong opinions, and I've only run into the limit a dozen or so times over the past 9 years. I really don't see this as a major block to meaningful participation. Stack Overflow proper gets far more posts than Meta, yet still has the same daily vote limits. Not *every* post you agree with merits an upvote (and vice versa for disagreement). Only the ones  that actually add something to the discussion.

Comment: "the daily voting limit isn't to restrict your participation—rather, it's to make you carefully consider the content for which you decide to vote" - except it disproportionately affects those participating and moderating more. If you're on the site for 1 hour a day with no moderation, you can probably vote on everything you see. A few hours with lots of moderation, not so much. I'm curious how many users even *know* about this limit, never mind regularly hitting it to the point of needing to vote more selectively. And is there evidence showing we're preventing "bad" instead of "good" votes?

Comment: Although if the limit is there to prevent abuse, or even prevent people from getting burnt out (which is a point I've seen raised before on related rate-limiting), fair enough. But that's not to say I think the way it's done is the best way to do things.

Comment: @Dukeling Yeah, I'm with you that the limit does in fact have the effect of simply curtailing the participation of dedicated users who have spent hours on the site in a single day (possibly among other, more positive effects). On the other hand, I'm also with Cody that there's no reason to remove the vote limit for *Meta in particular*, as suggested in the question here; whether Cody's broader defence of the vote limit is persuasive or not, the argument that a vote limit is an annoying obstacle to participation for dedicated users is not Meta-specific.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why users should be forced to vote only on the questions and comments they feel most strongly about. Why not scatter votes if the votes reflect an honest opinion? If the concern is that the most important issues wouldn't be as visible in a sea of increased voting, I don't think this is true; a rising tide lifts all boats. I'm not seeing how the increase would be negative. Just my observations; I've never had an issue with the limits myself.

Comment: I've hit the limit a couple of times before. My take is, if it's important enough for me to vote on something, I'll remember to vote on it tomorrow, and if I don't remember to vote on it tomorrow, it probably wasn't important enough to vote on it today.